# Is there any posibility that a HTTP request succeed after the timeout

Tags: http, timeout

I have encounter a problem like this: it seems that my server has received the http request from client after a timeout or some error return in client.
I am wondering that whether there is any posibility that my server can receive the http request after a timeout?
my code in client:

```
        while(1)
        {
            std::cout << "=====post once>>>>>>>>>>>" << std::endl;
            auto res = Post(route.c_str(), content, "text/plain");
            if((res == nullptr) || (res->status != 200))
                sleep(3);
            else
            {
                if (res) {
                //   std::cout << res->status << std::endl;
                std::cout << res->body << std::endl;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

i will retry to post after a timeout or a bad request. In some case with bad WIFI, the server received two http post in a very short peroid of time. It seemed that a http request reached the server first after a error or a timeout or something like that, then another http reqeust reached the server because the while(1).
anyone can answer my question? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can. The timeout could happen while server sends a response to the client due to network lag for example. In such a case server received the request, properly processed it and sended a response. Response just  didn't got to client.

In case you are repeating the requests from client side it's a good idea to design your API  so that server could handle duplicate requests correctly (include some id in the request for example).

Comment: thanks, @pin2t. thanks for the advice about sending requests with id, we are now planning to code like this